# Spatial Overlapping - Filter by % of Coverage

Tags: python, geopandas, spatial-join, spatial-filter

I am working with 2 Polygon Shapefiles: `parcels` & `wetlands`

Essentially what I want to accomplish is to filter the parcels dataset, where I only keep parcels that contain less than 50% Wetlands. For example the yellow parcels marked blue would be kept while the others would be filtered out, as the `wetlands` layer covers too much of the `parcel`

[image]

I've researched and tried various Spatial Joins, but none offer an option for %'s, and the `gpd.overlay` option only works on a DataFrame Level, not on individual polygons.

I was thinking some sort of comparison of Shape Areas, where:

`filtered_parcels = filtered_parcels[(wetlands['shape_area'] <= parcels['shape_area'] * 0.5)]`

However, I don't know how to obtain the Shape Area of the Wetlands contained only within a certain parcel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first dissolve the wetlands gdf down to a single shape. Then I would use geopandas.overlay to make a gdf of the overlapping areas.  I would calculate the area of the parcels and also overlapping areas e.g. using the area package, after converting to an equal-area projection like cea. Then a pandas merge between the parcels and overlapping gdfs would let you compare the areas.

Obviously a lot going on between the lines above - let me know if I need to expand on any points.